# Does expert system use algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, artificial-intelligence

I want to build an expert system for analyzing the personality of a number of people and then distribute them in groups , each group will have members with different personalities.

I have been reading about ES a lot but I still confused , does  rule-based system enough to build the system, or do I have to use matching algorithms like stable marriage or Maximum bipartite matching.

Comment: The title in your question is meaningless. Any computer program is an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expert systems are called "Experts" for a reason. They are cable of doing a particular job at up most perfection. Not 100% but 99%. Now I am no expert on these systems (pun intended) but as far as these two algorithms go my answer would be to try to boil down to the exact purpose of your system. These two algorithms do two different things. All in all what I am saying is to find an concrete job that your expert system will do. Using the **Stable Marriage** algorithm you will be ranking and connecting vertices with edges accordingly to their respective weights. As for the **Maximum Matching** algorithm you will be trying to find the lone vertices and edges. At this point according to your needs I would try to find something in between or edit the **Stable Marriage** algorithm to fits your needs.

Good luck! You have chosen to tackle a very strong problem ;)